# Android make http call given a WebResourceRequest

Tags: android, webresourcerequest

Given a WebResourceRequest which is a post request and has body how to i make an http call and get the response?

I know this sounds pretty basic butI'm having a problem getting the answer

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at Volley. It is quite powerful and easy to use and gets all your needs handled.

After implementing it if you are still getting nothing try PostMan with the same parameters as you are using to make the http call. If PostMan fails to show data then parameters are wrong.

Volley - https://developer.android.com/training/volley/

PostMan - https://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: Doesn't look like Volley supports `WebResourceRequest`

Comment: Check this - https://github.com/KonstantinSchubert/request_data_webviewclient Not sure why would you go through WebResourceRequest if you are using Volley.

Comment: I'm not using Volley